# Real-Time Data shows visits of pages that don't exist for the selected domain

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics, I have navigated to All Accounts-> SomeDomain.

I see a lot of traffic to that domain.
However, most pages listed there are from another domain of mine.

Real-Time for example shows this:

[image]

This is hilarious because this page doesn't exist on that domain.
I thought that it shows only traffic to the domain that I have selected above after "All accounts".

Is that not correct? 
Or does anybody know any situation where this might happen?
This goes on since months already.

My GA is managed via GTM.
I don't use any CMS.

In GTM, I have a GA Page View Trigger:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't see where I could have made a mistake.
Does anybody do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom report with dimension `Hostname` and metric `Sessions` (for example). You'll see what domains send data to your GA Property.

May be somebody stole code of your site (including trackers).

You can filter alien domains in GA settings for View.

[image]

UPD. Lookup table to push GA ID's depending on Hostname.

[image]

Comment: @MsEasy Thanks a lot. I can see that all domains are my own. But I have no idea how they got in there. On my websites, I have the GTM code, but that doesn't have to be specific to the domain. That is being fiddled out by GTM, right?

Comment: I have added more screenshots of my configuration.

Comment: @tmighty I need to understand structure. You have one GTM code for all domains. True? And unique GA ID for each domain. Look up table was created to push GA ID's to GA depending on hostname. True?

Comment: Yes, all this is true.

Comment: @tmighty I guess smth is wrong with Look up table. I never used this way. I'll add screenshot to my answer: how I see that.

Comment: My lookup table looks like this, except that "Output" don't result in the actual UA-IDs, but instead something like "{{TrackID mydomain.de}}" which is a Constant (you can see that in my last screenshot). I will give it a try and remove the {{TrackID mydomain.de}} and type out the actual UA-ID. Edit: For now, I have changed "Constant" to "Google Analytics settings" (which allowed me to insert a UA-ID), let's see if that fixes it.